How to disable code completion suggestions from other open source files in Code::Blocks?
Code::Blocks always shows suggestions from other open source files. For example, if I write a function in another file like func(int a, char ch), Code::Blocks will automatically suggest func(int a, char ch) when I type func in another file.
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int func(int a,char c)
{
    return 1;
}
int main()
{
    
    return 0;
}



How to configure the IDE to make Code::Blocks not show suggestions from other open source files.

Are both of the files part of the same project?

Could you please use Codeblocks Nightly Builds? The Codeblocks team said they will release a new version in Dec. but it's now that you should use a Nightly Build. There're many improved functionalities, like better code-completion using clangd. I suggest you visiting https://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,24357.0.html , https://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?board=20.0 and https://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/CB_Clangd_Client

no................
